# defining/initializing variables in alphabet list example

Tags: python

Why is it that you have to initialize/define the alphabet variable (as a list), but not the letter variable (as a character) in the code below? In the sample python code I’ve looked at sometimes variables are initialized/defined, sometimes they’re not. Confused.

Also, in the code below if you get rid of the alphabet = [] the code still works, but for some reason the alphabet list contains 2 copies of the alphabet, unlike when alphabet = [], in which case the alphabet list contains only one copy of the alphabet. Why is this?

```
# Create alphabet list of lowercase letters
alphabet = []
for letter in range(97,123):
    alphabet.append(chr(letter)
```

Comment: If it contains two copies of the alphabet, it's because the `alphabet` variable from you last run is still in scope. Are you doing this in a repl?

Comment: The `letter` variable is defined by your `for` statement.

Comment: Yes, and are you coming from another programming language? Would help us understand why you ask about the `letter` variable.

Comment: Also note that in the Python language list comprehensions are preferred over for loops in this case: `alphabet = [chr(letter) for letter in range(97,123)]` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that you have to initialize/define the alphabet variable (as a list), but not the letter variable (as a character) in the code below? In the sample python code I’ve looked at sometimes variables are initialized/defined, sometimes they’re not. Confused.

In the case of `alphabet`, you are modifying the list as you go by `append`ing to the end.  You can't append to a variable that doesn't exist.

For `letter`, the variable is initialized as soon as it is assigned a value in the loop.  By the time you try to do anything with it, it already exists because it has been assigned a value.

> Also, in the code below if you get rid of the alphabet = [] the code still works, but for some reason the alphabet list contains 2 copies of the alphabet, unlike when alphabet = [], in which case the alphabet list contains only one copy of the alphabet. Why is this?

This sounds like you are testing by running the same code multiple times in a single interpreter session.  If you don't clear out `alphabet` before the loop each time, then you will append to the same list multiple times, which will cause your values to be duplicated.